# Call a signal handler but still ignore the signal (Posix, C)

Tags: c, asynchronous, posix, interrupt

I want to catch a signal, set a global saying the signal was caught, and then return to my main loop afterwords. Here's my code.

```
int main(int mainargc, char **mainargv)
{
.
.
.
    sig_handler.sa_handler = sigint_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sig_handler.sa_mask);
    sig_handler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sig_handler, NULL);
.
.
. 
    while(1)
    {
    //main loop
    }
}

void sigint_handler(int signal)
{
    int saved_error = errno;

    g_sigint_happened = 1;

    //TODO -- send sigint to children

    errno = saved_error;

}
```

My problem is that my signal handler is called but my program is still terminating. I'm not sure how to tell the signal handler to return to main.

Comment: Normally execution resumes after handling a signal, unless the signal in question was SIGSEGV. Are you sure SIGINT is the signal your program is receiving?

Comment: No I'm not sure. Here's what my input to my program looks like.
I press ^C and I see read: Interrupted system call

Comment: “Interrupted system call” is not a sign that your program is dying from a signal. See @caf's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to make execution resume after the signal handler was called.

Your problem might be that the signal has interrupted some blocking system call in `main`, which will cause it to return an error with `errno` set to `EINTR`.  If you aren't specifcally checking for this and restarting the system call, then it's probably just going through a general error case which is causing your process to exit.

Comment: This is my problem, I'm smart. =P

Comment: You should just add `SA_RESTART` to the `sa_flags`. There's no need to deal with `EINTR` and restarting manually in modern programs unless you actually **want** the interrupting behavior (which is rarely useful; even in situations where it could in theory be useful, it has race conditions that defeat the purpose).

Comment: @R.: `SA_RESTART` doesn't apply to every syscall, though - for example the sleeping and file descriptor multiplexing ones.

Comment: Yes, for sleeping that's an issue. For `select`/`poll` it's rather irrelevant that they return early since you'll normally be calling them in a loop anyway and checking which descriptors are ready each time.

Comment: @R.: It's not so irrelevant if you're treating any error return as a fatal error, though - which is what the OP was doing here (albeit with `read()`, where `SA_RESTART` is effective).